# Rails has_many :through #new doesn't set associations on new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As per the Rails docs, one can use has_many :through as a shortcut:

> The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up
>   "shortcuts" through nested has_many associations. For example, if a
>   document has many sections, and a section has many paragraphs, you may
>   sometimes want to get a simple collection of all paragraphs in the
>   document.

So let's say we have this code:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sub_users
  has_many :settings
end

class SubUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :settings, through: :user
end

class Setting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Based on this, if I run `user.settings.new`, I get a new `Setting` instance with `user_id` set to `user.id`.

That's great. But if I run `sub_user.settings.new`, I get a new `Setting` instance that doesn't have `user_id` set to `sub_user.user.id`.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `has_many through:` for that, `delegate` looks like the best idea https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

```
class SubUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :settings, to: :user
end
```

Your current code is not what `has_many through` is for, check the docks, the relations are different https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I used to use delegate, but things start to break as soon as you need a SubUser.joins(:settings) for example, or a simple `.includes` to avoid n+1 queries. If you use `delegate`, you miss all the benefits of the ActiveRecord association; having said that, if Rails is not smart enough to pre-fill sub_user.settings.new with the correct ids, I think that's a small price to pay, since using my solution (which is part of the official docs - see the quoted part) I can at least use `.joins` and `.includes`

Comment: The quote on your question is about a model that `has_many` models and those models `has_many` models too. Your set up is a `belongs_to` which then `has_many` models. It's not the same (did you mean that quote?). Anyway, with delegate, I think you DO can use joins or includes, check the doc for nested joins https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level

Comment: No, you can't use joins neither includes with delegate.